# How to mask some characters in a textbox while entering information into it?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-3.0

I have a textbox on a windows form that takes a credit card number and it shows the number in plain text. I need to display "x" for the first 12 characters and only the last 4 digits should be displayed in plain text while entering information into it. Also, do we get the actual information from textbox's text property if we mask the value?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

I would just split the textbox in two parts, one masked using a [`MaskedTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fkc1cz6.aspx), the other plain for the last 4 digits. You get your functionality for free in this case, no need to reinvent the wheel. Use a [`Mask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx) property of "0000-0000-0000" and a passwordChar of 'X'.

Once a user has entered the first 12 digits, you can automatically set focus on the second textbox to set the remaining digits.

Comment: I'm assuming you're not a UI designer because that's a terrible solution from a usability point of view.

Comment: How so? Most forms to enter credit card info use separate text boxes

Comment: Users would not understand why one element (card number) is spilt unequally between two boxes. You're solving the problem by making it easy for the developer, but UI's should always focus on the viewpoint of the user.

Answer (score 2):

In your OnTextChanged event of the textbox, you should keep a tab of the number of entered char's and as long as that count is <= 12 you should replace the entered char's with a "x".

Comment: And store the entered characters before replacing them. Otherwise the .Text property will just return x's!